# How to traverse a neo4j graph using python neo4jrestclient

Tags: python, neo4j, rest-client, neo4j.py

I'm trying to follow the code example here: https://neo4j-rest-client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/traversals.html

```
n1.traverse(types=[client.All.Knows])[:]
```

But I don't understand what kind of obect 'client' is supposed to be, it wasn't defined in the example. When I try and do the same with my graphdb (one of the relations is 'belongsTo'), I get a `NameError: name 'client' is not defined` error:

```
from neo4jrestclient.client import GraphDatabase
gdb = GraphDatabase("http://myserver.....")

n = gdb.node[10]
ret = n.traverse(types=[client.All.belongsTo])
print ret
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need

```
from neo4jrestclient.client import All
```

And then use `All.belongsTo`.

In the docs, I am importing `client` directly.

```
from neo4jrestclient import client
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense now. Thanks Javier for this answer your useful library!